# How to display previous push notification using fcm in list-view

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently i am working in a project which receive Push notification using FCM, i am receiving notification quite well.

In next part of project , i have to make an ativity which will display all the previous notification. kind of action center.
any clue will help me a lot.

Comment: You can store incoming notifications into local database and display them in your listview.

Comment: Text in all-case is often perceived as yelling, which might explain why your questions attracted downvotes. I changed the case for you, but keep this in mind going forward please.

Answer (score 2):

For getting previous notifications, you have to save your notification in your database before sending the push notification.

After that you can fetch all the previous notification's data from your database.
You can use `firebase realtime database` or `firebase cloud firestore` database to save the data.